# How to use a for loop in to find out data by condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have DataFrame name **expense** which has a column name **price**. Now I want to make different DataFrame for price=50,100,500 respectively like df50 for price=50,df100 for price = 100,df 500 for price =500 from the original DataFrame expense. I have used the below code

```
pr=[32,50,75,110,150,210,260]
for i in pr:
    dfi = expence.loc[expence['price']==i]
```

But when I am doing `print(df50)`
it is showing

> NameError: name 'df50' is not defined.

I know it can be done by

```
df50 = expence.loc[expence['price']==50]
```

But I have to do it for so many values(almost100) in price. Because of that I want to use for loop.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue or any suggestion for better method.

Comment: Put the results in a dictionary, and use `df[i]`.

Comment: Mr. Barmer can you write a little bit code for me. I am very new to it so it will help me to understand. Actually I did not get how to use it.

Comment: I posted an answer a couple of minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pr=[32,50,75,110,150,210,260]
df = dict()
for i in pr:
    df[i] = expence.loc[expence['price']==i] # assign the value here

print(df[50])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
pr=[32,50,75,110,150,210,260]
df = {expense.loc[expence['price'] == i] for i in pr}
print(df[50])
```

Comment: It is showing TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, maybe you need to add `.str`?